# How do completely wipe Adobe Creative Cloud from my Yosemite OS X machine?

Tags: macos, installation, osx-yosemite

My Creative Cloud app was corrupted on install. Every time I try to open it, it crashes. It tells me to download the installer and re-install, but every I run the installer it tells me to go download "the installer" that I am already running. Then it sends me to the Adobe website.

Comment: https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-suite/kb/cs5-cleaner-tool-installation-problems.html

Comment: that should be an anwer